# Swift: SKAction.runBlock -> Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call BUT WHY?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm noobie in Swift. I can't figure out why this code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
  var statements = Statements()

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
       SKAction.sequence([
         SKAction.runBlock(addLabel(statements)),
         SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)
       ])
     ))
 }
 func addLabel(statements: Statements) {...}
}
```

Results to: Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yet another weird bug in the type checker.  Because the type of `self.addLabel(self.statements)` is not `Void -> Void` it's `Void`, the compiler assumed you were invoking another method somewhere else (where that somewhere else is, I have no clue.  There's no method named `runBlock(_:)` anywhere I can find).  Try an explicit closure when stuff like this happens

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var statements = Statements()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock({ self.addLabel(self.statements) }),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)
        ])))
    }

    func addLabel(statements: Statements) -> Void { }
}
```