# runBlock not working in sequence?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a basic spawn sequence- the block must be created, `moveDownLeft`, and then `removeLeft`. `moveDownLeft` and `removeLeft` work fine on their own when the block is added using `self.addChild(block1)` previously, however I need to have `self.addchild` within the sequence.

The only way that I can see to do this is use `runBlock`, and I looked at this question when I got an error using that: [Swift: SKAction.runBlock -> Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call BUT WHY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411883/swift-skaction-runblock-missing-argument-for-parameter-completion-in-call)

So now I am left with this:

```
 block1.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock({ self.addChild(self.block1) }), moveDownLeft, removeLeft]))
```

And nothing in the sequence works because the block is not created in the first place. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fragment is too short but it looks like a typical chicken and egg problem.

- node can only run actions once it has been added as child and thus becomes part of the scene graph
- your node is supposed to run an action that will eventually add itself to the scene graph but it's not in the scene graph yet so it won't run that action

Add the node as child first, then run the action. If you need the node to be inactive for some time, simply set it's visible property to NO for the duration. You kay also ned to change other properties, ie postpone creation of the physics body.